# Screen SVG file with a python webserver

Tags: python, svg, cgi

I want to screen a svg file in a webpage generate from a server.
Here is my server :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable() 

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("0.0.0.0", 8123)
handler.cgi_directories = ['/WEBSERVER']

httpd = server(server_address, handler)

try:    
    print "Running HTTP server"
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Server Stoped"
```

Here is my script:

```
import cgitb
import cgi
print 'Content-type: text/html'
    print '''
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    '''
print """<embed data="http://0.0.0.0:8123/WEBSERVER/358336657.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>"""
```

My server is launched from the repertory before WEBSERVER.
I tried with object, with img, with div with all different path, with or without http, in abosolute path or not, in /tmp, I tried with 777 chown with all combinaison of chmod, with all different DOCTYPE...none works
The only way to screen it is to open svg file and print the it, but I don't want that, I want to call it with the address.

Is there a solution to do it???

Comment: I'm not sure 0.0.0.0 is a valid IP address in this context. Have you tried 127.0.0.1 (localhost)?

Comment: no there is no impact when I change to this ip. I tried to add mimetype svg in the server script but it does not work I really don't know why...